# Laravel if statement for request object

Tags: laravel, isset, lumen

Currently building out an API. I am working on an update function with excepts the incoming request. so: api.dev.com/?api_key=asdf&storeid=2 etc

now in the backend i am accepting the Request and then i am trying to write some logic to check if the request includes storeid then update that entry etc.

But when i am writing my logic and i do

```
if(isset($request->storeid))
    $store->id = $request->storeid;
```

If I do not include storeid in my put request then i get:

```
Call to a member function parameter() on a non-object
```

Because it is not present. Am I approaching writing this logic the wrong way?

I want to leave it up to the users to update the records they want. So they should not have to include all the variables in the request. Just those that need to be updated.

Citti

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
if($request->has('storeid')) {
    ...
```

Comment: Very bad answer! You should use the has method to determine if a value is present on the request. The has method returns true if the value is present !! and is not an empty string!!!

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов huh? My answer does use the `has` method.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Call to a member function parameter() on a non-object" is not because you are not including the "storeid" input, but because you are not calling an instance of the Store object.

Maybe if you do something like:

```
if(isset($request->storeid))
  $store = Store::findOrFail($request->storeid)
```